# Not able to do Remote desktop (RDP) in both Staging & Production in Azure?

Tags: azure

I have enabled RDP in azure cloud service. I'm able to RDP staging but not able to RDP production. When i do VIP swap then i'm able to RDP to production and not able to RPD to staging.

Comment: Do you have deployments running in both staging *and* production? If yes, did you deploy the identical package, with identical RDP configuration?

Comment: Also: This probably fits better on SuperUser - it's not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes, first i deploy on staging and then i do the VIP swap and both environment has same configuration.

Comment: A VIP swap isn't a copy: It's a move: Staging <- -> Production. If you only deploy to Staging, then do a VIP swap, you only have something in production at that point.

Comment: it was working but since last week its not working. Do i have to delete the production instance and then do VIP same??

Answer (score 0):

What error (if any) are you receiving?

Are the RDP endpoints enabled for both the production and staging deployment slots/environments?